# Running a GAE Project Locally

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-luna

I am using eclipse luna. I created a web project based on a GAE folder of another google app engine project cloned from Github. 
When I run the new web project locally, I get a message on the console that  Dev App Server is now Running. On the browser when I type localhost:8888 it does not not load the required page instead, it brings the default webpage reading "Web Application Starter Project" Please enter your name:. "

What could be the problem, I have disabled gwt.

Comment: You are looking at the default GWT/GAE sample application for any new project that is created with the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: How can I solve that?

Comment: Easiest IMO : create a new GAE project but do not generate the sample code, there's an option for that. Next copy your code into the project and try to get it going.